# How to get full method name in eclipse plugin application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For example my method name is

```
public static Address convert(final com.test.Address wsAddress)throws Exception
```

I want the whole line.

If I do

```
IMethod[] methods=type.getMethods();
IMethod method=methods[0];
String mname=method.toString();
mname=mname.substring(0, mname.indexOf(")")+1);
```

I get only

```
Address convert(com.test.Address)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface `IMethod` extends the interface `IMember`. This interface provides a method called `getFlags()`, with which you can query the modifiers of the member in question. See this [method's documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMember.html&anchor=getFlags%28%29) for more details.

With the help of other query methods (e.g. `getElementName()`, `getParameterNames()`, `getReturnType()`, ...), you must assemble the whole method signature as it appears in the source. There is no way to call only one method and get the whole source declaration line.

---

EDIT

If you want to get the full method source code, you can also invoke the method `getSource()`. However, that will also provide the method's body. So the question should be: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: but if the method has public,static,final eg public static final fun()  how do i order them when i use getFlags? and get the whole method name?

Comment: Simply put: There is no ordering. So you cannot retrieve any oredering with the `getFlags()` method. Other question: What are you trying to achieve? Without more information, I cannot help you.